# Postman POST запрос

Tags: api, postman

Не могу разобраться как сделать post запрос через Postman 
С GET запросами все просто. 
Так не выходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так тоже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В документации вроде все написано, но куда именно вписывать параметры и их значения ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы запрос успешно сделали, сервер успешно ответил кодом 405, всё хорошо